# Dynamic Post Type Variable echo as string?

Tags: php

Working on a Wordpress Theme. I'm trying to make dynamic post-type names. My code is throwing error but I feel like I'm close... what am I missing? my variables are correct, but the coding within the 'label' and such is not correct.

EDIT: got the 'label' to process but it is not pulling my variable. It is displaying "Page" when it should display my input. Any ideas why?

```
$novus_comedy_to = get_option('novus_comedy_to');

// register comedy post type
register_post_type( 'comedy' , $args );

add_action('init', 'comedy_videos');

function comedy_videos() {
    $args = array(
        'label' => __($novus_comedy_to),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        // this controls whether or not post can have category format
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'tags',),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'comedy', 'with_front' => true )
    );

    register_post_type( 'comedy' , $args );
}
```

This is how the labels were normally:

```
'label' => __('Comedy'),
'singular_label' => __('Comedy'),
```

Comment: Please review [the Codex entry on `register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) - `singluar_label` is not a valid argument, and there's really not many reasons to ever touch the `_builtin` argument unless you are developing a core patch - I suggest deleting it. We cannot aide you with your `unexpected T_ECHO` error as it regards a missing closing bracket `)` before a call to `echo()`, and the posted code contains no calls to `echo()`, nor does it contain any mis-matched brackets.

Comment: I suggest reading [I18n for WordPress Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) in Codex, you've got some misunderstandings about how this whole thing works.

Comment: I will read up on both of your links but I am not a PHP guy. Im a designer trying to learn it. its like hitting a brick wall when I try to code in it... for now I need the variable to display via my theme-options tag. Right now it disregards my variable and outputs "Pages" instead of display the custom post type label "Comedy", as it was originally. Is there a fix? I can worry about writing better post types later. :)

Comment: This isnt a plugin, Milo. Its a built in theme I am developing from scratch. If I cant figure out a custom post type dynamic variable exchange how am I supposed to figure out i18n...

Comment: @Flannel - if you don't intend on supporting internationalization techniques (or don't want to trouble yourself with learning it now), remove the I18n functions from your code - i.e. instead of `'label' => __($novus_comedy_to)` just use `'label' => $novus_comedy_to`. The Codex entry is somewhat misleading in that I18n functions are just as applicable in themes as they are in plugins.

Comment: @boscho I've saved the internationalization link, but for now I am trying to get my [site](http://www.elevancement.com/) up to a crawl :) I hope you understand. Im trying to start with what I know and learn more advanced stuff later on. Ill try that code change and see if I can get it working correctly. I assume I can use the same $novus_comedy_to for my 'slug' as well?

    `'slug' => $novus_comedy_to`

Comment: I also recommend checking that the `'novus_comedy_to'` option has the value that you expect it should. PHP's [`die()/exit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) and [`var_dump()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) will prove to be invaluable tools - the former kills script execution with a message, and the latter displays the contents and structure of variables/evaluated expressions. This in mind, `echo('novus_comedy_to:'); die( var_dump( $novus_comedy_to ) );` will stop WordPress in it's tracks and display the value of `$novus_comedy_to`.

Comment: I totally understand - I'm decently far into my WordPress career and I still haven't fully tackled I18n/L10n ;) . Now that we have a better idea of where you're at, though, our community can provide you with better advice and answers. On that note, insert `define( 'WP_DEBUG', TRUE );` into your `wp-config.php` file to enable debug messages if you haven't already.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the assistance. Its a Wordpress theme for Youtubers. Comedy, Action, Horror, Guests would be the categories in Post Types. They enter the title and the Youtube 11 digit ID and it outputs the video in the category on the front page. I want them to have the ability to change the Comedy, Action, Horror, and Guests names in the Dashboard to whatever they want. I can output the titles anywhere I need. Ill go ahead and throw the define wp debug code in, but where do I place the `echo('novus_comedy_to:'); die( var_dump( $novus_comedy_to ) );`?

Comment: Im a graphic designer turned web dev, so php is quite difficult.

Comment: `rewrite => slug` can indeed share the value of `$novus_comedy_to`, but note that "slug"s' intended purpose is for use in URLs - if `$novus_comedy_to` is not URL-friendly (or URL-encoded) it could create issues. If the argument is omitted, WordPress will default to assigning the actual post-type string to slug (in this case, `'comedy'`) which is frequently alright - but whether or not you explicitly set slug and what you set it to are mostly a matter of personal preference as well as the specific needs of your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15135/discussion-between-boscho-and-flannelbeard).